# Latex output is in landscape format, the PDF is not

Tags: latex, tex

I am using \begin{landscape} in LaTex to make the output in landscape format, but the PDF file produced is not in landscape.  The result is that all the text is sideways and is very inconvenient to read.  Is there any way to turn the page to make the text run horizontally instead of vertically?

To describe the issue more clearly, the PDF which is created is in portrait, but the text on the PDF runs vertically.
If I were to print the PDF, it would appear landscape instead of portrait, but really is portrait if seen on a computer.

Comment: Hi! _To describe the issue more clearly_, please add minimal code reproducing the problem. Including the header so users can compile and correct where necessary!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add

```
\usepackage{pdflscape}
```

to your document preamble, the PDF should be formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I poked around on google for an answer, and I found that it is possible to not use `\begin{landscape}` but to use

```
\usepackage[paperheight=8.5in,%
            paperwidth=13.0in,%
            margin=0.5in,%
            headheight=0.0in,%
            footskip=0.5in,%
            includehead,%
            includefoot]{geometry}
```

Instead of rotating the text, it changes the size and margins of the PDF produced to appear landscape on both the computer and when printed.